# odd vertex behavior when translating or editing

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices

I have a woman 3d model that I've been working on for a while. After I've fully  meshed, skinned, morphed, tweaked and textured for third time, I'm getting this maddening glitch:

[image]

The hand has 4 vertices that jump to that same location. Notice that its just the hand model and I've removed all modifiers, weights, vertex groups and shape keys.

I'm trying to figure out how to fix this. It would be very disappointing to have to rework the mesh yet again

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Turn off X mirror under options and all is well.

...or turn off Topology mirror if you need the X Mirror.

Comment: That worked! Any idea why the problem is on just those vertices?

Comment: It is trying to create a mirror across the X-Axis but why it chooses the ring finger I have no clue. If you create a mirror duplicate across the X-Axis then it all behaves as you would expect. Compliments on the topography by the way.